# Moving to Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some legacy code, this is called from the class with the main method to force the application to shut down and stop all deletion threads which might be running.

```
private void stopFileDeletionThreads() {
    //as activeCount could be wrong, repeat it until no DeletionThread is found
    boolean bFound = false;
    while (true) {
        bFound = false;
        ThreadGroup tg = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        if (tg != null) {
            int count = tg.activeCount();
            Thread[] tArray = new Thread[count];
            tg.enumerate(tArray);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (tArray[i].getClass().equals(DeletionThread.class)) {
                    bFound = true;
                    ((DeletionThread) tArray[i]).setRunStatus(false);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!bFound) {
            break;
        }
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        _logger.finest("Ignored interrupted exception when waiting after thread directory removal.");
    }
}
```

This is the DeletionThread:

```
public class DeletionThread extends Thread {
private File _fDirToDelete;
private boolean _bRun;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param fDirToDelete direcotory to remove.
 */
public HsaBrokerDeletionThread(File fDirToDelete) {
    _fDirToDelete = fDirToDelete;
    _bRun = true;
}

/**
 * Thread run method.
 */
public void run() {
    if (_fDirToDelete == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!_fDirToDelete.exists()) {
        return;
    }
    removeFolders(_fDirToDelete);
}

private void removeFolders(File f) {
    if (f == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!_bRun) {
        return;
    }
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        File fChildren[] = f.listFiles();
        if (fChildren != null) {
            for (File fTmp : fChildren) {
                if (!_bRun) {
                    return;
                }
                removeFolders(fTmp);
            }
        }
    }
    f.delete();
}


public void setRunStatus(boolean bRun) {
    _bRun = bRun;
}
```

The code that starts the deletion thread is in another class:

```
DeletionThread dt = new DeletionThread(f);
dt.start();
```

I am moving to use an ExecutorService and Runnable class instead of extending Thread. If the above becomes something like:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executorService.execute(new DirectoryRemover(directory));
executorService.shutdown();
```

My doubt is how to replicate the code in stopFileDelectionThreads when the application is force shut down to stop these deletion threads. Maybe it isn't necessary or I could make the executor service work with daemon threads but I read this is not a good idea when working with i/o.

Another idea was instead of making a newSingleThreadExecutor each time in the method, have one instance of a newCachedThreadPool which could be accessed with a getmethod and call shutdown on this. But then I'm not sure.

Bear in mind I can't rewrite everything, small steps. Thanks.

Comment: side comment: your existing DeletionThread is not thread safe...

Comment: Have you considered shutting down the executor using the shudownHook provided by the Runtime class?

Answer (score 0):

> I am moving to use an ExecutorService and Runnable class instead of extending Thread.

It is actually almost trivial to transform an `extends Thread` to an `implements Runnable` so long as the code does not do silly things.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

    /**
     * Thread run method.
     */
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Do something as a Thread.");
    }

}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    /**
     * Thread run method.
     */
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Do something as a Runnable.");
    }

}

public void test() {
    // Start the `Thread`
    Thread t = new MyThread();
    t.start();
    // Start the `Runnable`.
    Thread r = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
    r.start();
}
```

The *silly* things I mentioned include calling `sleep()` instead of `Thread.sleep()` etc. and can generally be fixed trivially.

The less trivial question of how to transform your existing code to use `Executors` really requires a little more detail like what triggers the creation of a `DeletionThread`.